# Is there a command to get bash to print a new prompt string and redraw the current line?

Tags: command-line, bash, cmd.exe, ps1

Instead of waiting for slow commands to finish, I'd like to run them in the background. However, when they finish running and print to stdout, I get (where `█` represents my cursor) this:

```
$ slowcmd &
$ cmd_output
█
```

- There is no prompt string before my cursor.
- and `slowcmd` can be any slow command (For the stuff I've tried, I just said `alias slowcmd='sleep 1 && echo cmd_output'`)

Whereas I'd like something like this:

```
$ slowcmd && redrawPromptString &
$ cmd_output
$ █
```

**Where after the command's output, a new Prompt String is printed out for me.**

What I can do to make `redrawPromptString` do what I want? I've tried `clear`, `kill $$` to send a `^C` to the terminal, and finally `printf "^C"` (of course that didn't work). I'm running bash. (GNU bash, version 3.2.57).

Comment: My PS1 is colored and uses backslash-escaped special characters - like `\@` for the time. (But yeah, that is a suitable workaround for any sane person who doesn't care about getting exactly what he wants...) Ahaha but for real, I hate not being able to do what I want out of ignorance! Out of lack of support in the program I'm using? Sure (for now). But out of ignorance? I don't like that. I will google and stack overflow and ask everyone who I think might now until the cows come home.

Comment: Why not to use separate, dedicated for `slowcmd` terminal? Use terminal multiplexer such as `tmux`, create new window and run there `slowcmd` while you can switch back to working terminal and continue your work.

Comment: @Alex I can also open up a new tab in iTerm. I'm not asking how to gain control of my terminal while doing commands that take some time, because I already know how to do that. And if I asked a question like that, I'd get rightfully downvoted. No, I'm not looking for a heuristic, I'm looking for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `redraw-current-line` function of `bind` builtin. First check if it's already bound maybe:

```
bind -q redraw-current-line
```

I've never seen it bound by default, so you will probably need to bind it. Pick a key combination, let's say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. Check if it's already taken:

```
bind -p | grep -F '"\C-y'
```

Empty output means the combination is unused. If so, let's bind `redraw-current-line` to it:

```
bind "\C-y":redraw-current-line
```

Now, whenever a background process messes with your command line, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. Then your prompt will be redrawn along with whatever command you have just partially typed (if any), so you can continue as if nothing happened.

To make the binding permanent you could add the above command to your `~/.bashrc`, but don't. The right approach is to modify `~/.inputrc` (for user) or `/etc/inputrc` (system-wide). This way any program that uses `readline(3)` library will obey. The line to add to either file looks like this:

```
"\C-y":redraw-current-line
```

But if you create `~/.inputrc` anew, make sure its first line says `$include /etc/inputrc`. This is because up to this point `readline` has used `/etc/inputrc` and maybe your workflow relies on what's in this file. From now on, the library will use your `~/.inputrc` instead; the line `$include /etc/inputrc` makes it parse the system-wide file as well.

For more info see `help bind` and `man 3 readline`.

Comment: I've been using `"\C-c"`, which sends a `INTR character` according to `stty`, and causes all input to be discarded and the prompt script to be presented again. But `redraw-current-line` is exactly what I was looking for! It doesn't lose my current input OR screen history. I don't mean to be greedy, but do you know of any CLI command that can invoke a `Readline` function?

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation on `bind`, too. It's super super tough to find good documentation on it. Man bash has good stuff under Shell Builtin Commands (if you can find it through all the cruft). For anyone else reading, this [link](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/bind.htm) is only about `bind`, and I found it much more noob friendly.

Answer (score 1):

If you press `Ctrl+L`, it will partially do what you want. It will redraw the current line including everything you typed up to that point including the cursor position, but it will clear the screen, so your previous output is lost (or in case of a terminal window in the scrollback buffer). On the other hand, you were willing to try `clear`, so maybe that is not a problem.

Comment: Yeah, `clear` and `^L` don't do what I want. I want the command finishing to create a new prompt, so I don't have to manually do anything. There's gotta be a way! I've been using `^C` or `^L` or just plain `<Enter>`, they all _work_. But I'm doing a sub-optimal thing outta ignorance, and I hate that!

Comment: You won't get a new prompt, because the prompt has already been printed. But you can use `set -b` so that the shell will immediately print the ` [1]+  Done` and your cursor will be on a new line. You can also `trap` the `SIGCHLD` and use it to print a new prompt, but you would have to find out whether is was a background process that ended.