# Pipe command's output to different tmux pane

Tags: tmux

Imagine I have a command that produces lots of output and a return code, and I need to run it frequently (e.g. every minute) in a loop.

Is it possible to send the output of the command to a different tmux pane? Then I could split the current pane and see the long output (scrollable) in one of them and a list like *10:00 - Returned 7 \n 10:01 - Returned 5 \n 10:03 - Returned 9* in the current one.

So far, I've only found ways to *execute* commands in different tmux panes, which is not what I need. I need just a way to pipe the output of the command to another pane which then displays it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261537/108618

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1356682/432690) is quite close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @Kamil Maciorowski, I've figured it out:

The main thing to learn is: *I can pipe into another tty; anything I pipe there, will appear there*.

With my Cygwin, I have to adapt [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261537/205391), since piping to the `fd` of the shell's process just gives me errors; instead, I have to look where the `fd` symlink actually points at – piping there is no problem.

1. Get the shell's PID:

   ```
    echo $$
   ```
2. Look where its `fd` points at:

   ```
    $ ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd/1
   ```
3. From the resulting string like `lrwxrwxrwx 1 ... ... ... ... /proc/<PID>/fd/1 -> /dev/pty4` take the last bit and you know where to pipe to.

---

**Put together**:

This alias tells the path where to pipe to for having the output in the current pane:

```
    alias nameOfCurrentTTY='ls -l /proc/`echo $$`/fd/1 | sed "s/^.* -> //"'
```

---

**Update/extension**: When using bash, it is possible to display the current shell (eg. `pty2`) in the prompt by adding `\l` to it ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html)).